# Alexa skill 2 intents and open slot

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Is it possible that Alexa reacts right when I have in a sample utterances something like this, opened slots?

```
MyNameIsIntent {firstname}
ProjektIntent {projekt}
```

Right now she always goes back to  MyNameIsIntent even if she ask a question for a ProjektIntent

The bad conversation:

```
Alexa: Welcome, what is your name?
Me: Frank
Alexa Hi Frank, Tell me what project is interesting for you?
Me: Teleshoping
Alexa: Hi Teleshoping, Tell me what project is interesting for you?
```

Im totally new to Alexa, could you give me please a tip if it is possible that Alexa answers the right question? I tried to do it with a session atributes but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use States do react differently on the same intents depending on the state of your application.

See https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs#making-skill-state-management-simpler for the official documentation.

You create a dictionary of StateHandlers like this (in Node.js 4.3):

```
var askNameStateHandlers = Alexa.CreateStateHandler("askNameState", 
    {
         "MyIntent": function () { /* ... */ }
        // more handlers ...
    });
```

Then you register your handlers like this, assuming you have a dictionary of handlers without states `defaultHandlers` and two with handlers for a specific state `askNameStateHandlers` and `askProjectStateHandlers`:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.registerHandlers(defaultHandlers, askNameStateHandlers, askProjectStateHandlers);
    alexa.execute();
};
```

To change the state of your application, simply assign it like this inside a handler function:

```
this.handler.state = "askNameState";
```

The `alexa-sdk` will then take care of calling the right handler depending on your application state.

There is also a full example implementation at https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-highlowgame

---

Note that this way, you will only have one intent `MyIntent` who accepts the answers to both questions, deciding which of your functions should handle the result based on the application state only.

Answer (score 2):

An utterance file like that won't work.  Alexa uses the text of the utterance - the stuff aside from the slot name, of which you have none - to choose an intent.

So, unfortunately you can't design your interactions to allow for a response of just 'Teleshoping'.  Instead, the user would have to say something like 'I'm interested in Teleshoping' (you would need to tell them to say it like that), and the sample utterance would be 'I'm interested in {projekt}'.

Answer (score 0):

And just to add a little further clarification to Tom's answer, Alexa can't tell if the word "teleshoping" is your first name or project.
If you use longer utterances as Tom mentions, such as "my name is {firstname}" and "I want to {projekt}" then Alexa will have no trouble discerning.
You can also help Alexa tell the difference by filling in the slot values, but this assumes that you know what the possible projekt values will be.
firstname can use the builtin AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME slottype.